# Shiny button doesn't work

Tags: r, shiny

Can someone explain why button in VIP menuSubItem(inputID = traziVIP) doesn't work? If I click button in HT menuSubItemit it works. But in VIP doesn't work. I think it is some stupid mistake but I can't figure it out.
Here is the code of the up:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
# library(webshot)
# library(RSelenium)

source(file.path("ImenAuto_functions.R"), local = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")

# APP
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "ImenAuto")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Imenici", tabName = "imenici", icon = icon("phone"),
             menuSubItem("HT", tabName = "ht"),
             menuSubItem("VIP", tabName = "vip"))
  ))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ht",
            fluidRow(
              tabBox(
                tabPanel(title = "", 
                         fileInput("fileHT", "Izaberite csv file", 
                                   accept = c("text/csv", ".csv"), buttonLabel = "Pronađi datoteku",
                                   placeholder = "Nema podataka"),
                         br(),
                         actionButton("traziHT", "Traži brojeve"),
                         br(),
                         br(),
                         dataTableOutput("input_tablica")
                         )
              )
            )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "vip",
            fluidRow(
              tabBox(
                tabPanel(title = "", 
                         fileInput("fileVIP", "Izaberite csv file za pretragu VIP imenika", 
                                   accept = c("text/csv", ".csv"), buttonLabel = "Pronađi datoteku",
                                   placeholder = "Nema"),
                         br(),
                         actionButton(inputId = "traziVIP", "Traži brojeve"),
                         br(),
                         br(),
                         dataTableOutput("input_tablica_VIP")
                )
              )
            )
    )
  )
)

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  user <- reactive({
    session$user
  })

  user_account <- reactive({
    if (is.null(user())){
      return("nepoznato/lokalno")
    } else{
      return(user())
    }
  })

  # observeEvent(input$fileHT, {
  #   x <- read.csv2(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
  #   validate(
  #     need(ncol(x) < 2, 'Check at least one letter!')
  #   )
  # })


  brojevi_ht <- eventReactive(input$traziHT,{
    withProgress(message = 'Traženje brojeva u imeniku HT-a',{

      inFile <- input$fileHT

      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)

      x <- read.csv2(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
      validate(
        need(ncol(x) < 3, 'Input tablica može imati najviše dvije kolone')
      )
      # x <- read.csv2("E:/data/R/ShinyApps/ImenAuto/sample.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      #               encoding = "UTF-8") # TEST
      # guess_encoding(x)
      if(ncol(x) == 1){gdje <- rep(NA, nrow(x))}else{gdje <- x[,2]}
      tko <- x[,1]
      if (length(tko) <= 5){
        df_final <- list()
        for (j in 1:length(tko)){
          ## fill and submit form
          ht <- html_session("http://imenik.tportal.hr", encoding = "UTF-8")
          form <- html_form(ht)[[1]]
          fake_submit_button <- list(name = 'brzaPretragaSearchForm',
                                     type = "submit",
                                     value = NULL,
                                     checked = NULL,
                                     disabled = NULL,
                                     readonly = NULL,
                                     required = FALSE)
          attr(fake_submit_button, "class") <- "input"
          form[["fields"]][["submit"]] <- fake_submit_button
          from_filled <- form %>% set_values(tko = tko[j], gdje = gdje[j])
          session <- submit_form(ht, from_filled)
          # webshot(session$url, paste0(session$response$cookies$value, ".png"))
          # remDr$navigate("https://imenik.tportal.hr")
          # remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[@id='tko']")$clearElement()
          # Sys.sleep(1L)
          # remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[@id='tko']")$sendKeysToElement(list(tko[j]))
          # 
          # remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[@id='gdje']")$clearElement()
          # Sys.sleep(1L)
          # remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[@id='gdje']")$sendKeysToElement(list(gdje[j], key = "enter"))
          # Sys.sleep(2L)
          # remDr$screenshot(display = FALSE, file = paste0("tet.png"))
          # doc <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

          # Scrap
          x <- read_html(session, encoding = "UTF-8")
          # write_xml(doc, file="temp.html")
          to <- x %>% 
            html_nodes("#pretragaContainerInner_brzaPretraga > div > div") %>% 
            html_children() %>% 
            length(.)

          df <- list()
          for (i in 1:to){
            naziv <- x %>% 
              html_nodes(paste0('#pretragaContainerInner_brzaPretraga > div > div > div:nth-child(', i, ') > div.ImenikContainerInnerDetailsLeft.borderGrey > div')) %>% 
              html_text()
            adresa <- x %>% 
              html_nodes(paste0('#pretragaContainerInner_brzaPretraga > div > div > div:nth-child(', i, ') > div.ImenikContainerInnerDetailsLeft.borderGrey > ul > li.secondColumn > div:nth-child(1)')) %>% 
              html_text()
            mjesto <- x %>% 
              html_nodes(paste0('#pretragaContainerInner_brzaPretraga > div > div > div:nth-child(', i, ') > div.ImenikContainerInnerDetailsLeft.borderGrey > ul > li.secondColumn > div:nth-child(2)')) %>% 
              html_text()
            brojevi <- x %>% 
              html_nodes(paste0('#pretragaContainerInner_brzaPretraga > div > div > div:nth-child(', i, ') > div.ostaliPodaciContainer > div > div.ostalipodaciTextInner')) %>% 
              html_text() %>%
              stringr::str_extract_all(., "\\d+") %>%
              unlist() %>%
              paste0(., collapse = ", ")
            if(brojevi == "" | is.null(brojevi)){
              brojevi <- x %>%
                html_nodes(paste0('#pretragaContainerInner_brzaPretraga > div > div > div:nth-child(', i, ') > div.imenikSearchResultsRight > div.imenikTelefon')) %>%
                html_text()
            }
            podaci_request_names <- c("url", names(lapply(unlist(session$response$all_headers), `[[`, 1)))
            podaci_request <- c(session$response$url, lapply(unlist(session$response$all_headers), `[[`, 1))
            names(podaci_request) <- NULL
            podaci_request <- unlist(podaci_request)
            names(podaci_request) <- podaci_request_names
            podaci_request <- as.matrix(t(rep(podaci_request[1:4], length(brojevi))), nrow = length(brojevi))

            df[[i]] <- cbind(Input = tko[j], gdje[j], naziv, adresa, mjesto, brojevi, podaci_request)
            # df[[i]] <- cbind(Input = tko[j], gdje[j], naziv, adresa, mjesto, brojevi)

          }
          df_merge <- df[lapply(df,length)>3]
          df_final[[j]] <- do.call(rbind, df_merge)
        }

        # save
        ht <- do.call(rbind, df_final)
      }else{
        ht <- data.frame(`Najviše_tri_retka` = "Tablica sadrži više od tri retka")
      }
      # remDr$close()
      ht
    })
  })

  output$input_tablica <- renderDataTable({
    MyDataTable(brojevi_ht())
  }, server = FALSE)
  # observeEvent(input$TraziBrzoNekretnine, {
  #   broj <- loadDataUsers(table_users, user_account())$paket
  #   updateData(broj, user_account())
  # })


  brojevi_vip <- eventReactive(input$traziVIP,{
    withProgress(message = 'Traženje brojeva u imeniku VIP-a',{

      inFileVIP <- input$fileVIP

      if (is.null(inFileVIP))
        return(NULL)

      x <- read.csv2(inFileVIP$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
      validate(
        need(ncol(x) < 4, 'Input tablica može imati najviše tri kolone')
      )
      # x <- read.csv2("E:/data/R/ShinyApps/ImenAuto/sample_vip.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      #               encoding = "UTF-8") # TEST
      # guess_encoding(x)
      if(ncol(x) == 1){gdje <- rep(NA, nrow(x))}else{gdje <- x[,3]}
      tko <- x[,1]
      tko_2 <- x[,2]
      if (length(tko) <= 5){
        df <- list()
        for (j in 1:length(tko)){
          ## fill and submit form
          vip <- html_session("http://www.vipnet.hr/imenik", encoding = "UTF-8")
          form <- html_form(vip)[[1]]
          from_filled <- form %>% set_values(fname = tko[j], lname = tko_2[j], lname = gdje[j])
          session <- submit_form(vip, from_filled)

          # Scrap
          x <- read_html(session, encoding = "UTF-8")

          df[[j]] <- x %>%
            html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='p_p_id_imenik_WAR_vipnetimenikr_INSTANCE_fIgPMrz3HY2I_']/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div/div") %>%
            html_text() %>%
            str_split(., "  ") %>%
            do.call(rbind, .) %>%
            as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
          if(length(df[[j]]) == 0){df[[j]] <- as.data.frame(t(rep(NA, 6)))}
          colnames(df[[j]]) <- c("rbr", "imePrezime", "adresa", "grad", "posta", "broj")
        }
        df_final <- do.call(rbind, df)
      }
      df_final
    })
  })

  output$input_tablica_vip <- renderDataTable({
    MyDataTable(brojevi_vip())
  }, server = FALSE)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

the most important part is line 212. Why Event reactive function doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was a typo...